# How do you send an update to everyone using a website simultaneously with AngularJS and Firebase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, httprequest

So, say I and 3 friends are using the same website all from 3 separate computers at the same time. We each have profiles stored within an array on it that appear somewhat like:

```
$scope.profilesRanking = [
    {name:"Bob", score: 3000},
    {name:"John", score: 2500},
    {name:"Carl", score: 100}
]
```

Note, that these profiles are sorted by the value of their scores, and what I'd like to achieve is that without have to press the refresh button within a web browser, I'd like the changes across the site to occur as they happen. So, if Carl and John both gain 3000 points, all users score boards should be updated without stopping any other major processes.

All 3 users should instantly see:

```
$scope.profilesRanking = [
    {name:"John", score: 5500},
    {name:"Carl", score: 3100},
    {name:"Bob", score: 3000}
]
```

I am using Firebase to store this data, but I wonder how I can periodically check the values in the database without overflowing it with requests. The only way that comes to mind is to do it this way, where I send a request to the database every second, but I feel like that isn't a great approach.

Comment: If you are using Firebase, you don't need to keep checking the server again and again for updates. That is the #1 job of the Firebase Database, is to keep your references on all of your clients in sync.

Comment: Can you show us your Firebase code?

Comment: @frosty As of now it is only getters and setters. I kind of want my data to update without having to press a button.

Comment: That is the magic of firebase. Let me work up an example.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use `angular-fire`, which is a library to make working with AngularJS and Firebase easier. [The quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md) on their repo is has ALL OF THE STEPS you need to get going.

Answer (score 0):

With Firebase you can add a value-change listener, that calls a callback in your angular code, whenever the referenced object (or any child objects) is changed in your Firebase store.

This is how you do it:

```
function startListening(){
    var ref = new Firebase('yoururl');

    ref.on('value').then(function(snapshot){
        // This callback will be called every time the object referenced by 'ref'
        // or any children, is changed.
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.profilesRanking = snapshot.val();
        });
    });
}
```

The `$scope.$apply` is used to let angular know it's supposed to trigger a digest cycle.

This is possible because behind the scenes, Firebase uses websockets to transfer data, rater than regular asynchronous http requests.